# Why do my event handlers for button clicks stop when a different button is clicked?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this program i want the time to continue on each button even if another is clicked, yet, time seems to stop on a button when another is click i any suggestions here?

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import time

class Application(Frame):

##########################################################################    
  def my_timeDrag(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    min = 5
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Button3.configure(text="{}:{}".format(min,sec))
      self.Button3.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
    if sec == 0:
        min -= 1
        sec = 59
    elif min == 0:
        min = 5
##########################################################################################

  def my_timeBB(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    min = 4
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Button1.configure(text="{}:{}".format(min,sec))
      self.Button1.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
    if sec == 0:
         min -= 1
         sec = 59
    elif min == 0:
         min = 4


#######################################################   
  def my_timeRB(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    min = 4
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Button2.configure(text="{}:{}".format(min,sec))
      self.Button2.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
    if sec == 0:
          min -= 1
          sec = 59
    elif min == 0:
          min = 4

########################################################

  def createButtons(self):                                          # creats a button
    self.Button1 = Button(self)
    self.Button1["text"] = "Blue Buff"
    self.Button1["fg"]   = "Blue"
    self.Button1["command"] = self.my_timeBB                       # suppose to implement countdown in button text when click.

    self.Button1.pack({"side": "left"})

    self.Button2 = Button(self)
    self.Button2["text"] = "Red Buff"
    self.Button2["fg"] = "Red"
    self.Button2["command"] = self.my_timeRB

    self.Button2.pack({"side":"right"}) 
    self.Button2.pack(padx=50)

    self.Button3 = Button(self)
    self.Button3["text"] = " Dragon "
    self.Button3["fg"] = "Pink"
    self.Button3["bg"] = "Purple"
    self.Button3["command"] = self.my_timeDrag

    self.Button3.pack(side="bottom",pady=50)

    self.Quit = Button(self)
    self.Quit["text"] = "Quit"
    self.Quit["command"] = self.quit

    self.Quit.pack()
##############################################################


##############################################################    
  def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)                                   # initializes window
        self.pack()
        self.createButtons()

root = Tk()
root.title("Jungle Timer by BabyAchilles")
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Application(master=root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that ***Button*** from tkinter just only implement the command function whenever the user clicks on that button. Therefore, when the user clicks on another button, that command function will stop/terminate and change to the clicked button command function. That's the main reason why your timer stops!

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. The easiest way is to store your timer (such as Button1 minutes, secs, Button2 minutes, secs,...) as attributes and to use tkinter *Label* to display the timer for each of them on the interface instead of dealing your problem about the ***Button*** since the command function will always stop and change to another one whenever the user clicks on the buttons.
2. Another way to solve this problem is to use the `.invoke()` method in the ***Button*** widget to call back the command functions from previous clicked buttons. If you want to use this way, you can look up on this link about how this method works: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html

P/S: I love League of Legends, too!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Here is my code demo for the timer, so check it out! I used `.after()` method for the root window. Also, I stored all my time data as an object attribute, so it's easier to access!

```
import tkinter
import time

DEFAULT_FONT = ('Helvetica',30)
class LoL_JungleTimer():
    def __init__(self):
        self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()

        Dragon_button = tkinter.Button(master = self._root_window, text = 'Dragon', fg = 'purple', command = self._dragon_start)
        BlueBuff_button = tkinter.Button(master = self._root_window, text = 'Blue Buff', fg = 'blue', command = self._blue_buff_start)
        RedBuff_button = tkinter.Button(master = self._root_window, text = 'Red Buff', fg = 'red', command = self._red_buff_start)

        self._blue_buff_label = tkinter.Label(master = self._root_window, text = '5:00', fg = 'blue', font = DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._red_buff_label = tkinter.Label(master = self._root_window, text = '5:00', fg = 'red', font = DEFAULT_FONT)
        self._dragon_label = tkinter.Label(master = self._root_window, text = '6:00', fg = 'purple', font = DEFAULT_FONT)

        Dragon_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        BlueBuff_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        RedBuff_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self._blue_buff_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self._red_buff_label.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self._dragon_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.drag_minute = 5
        self.drag_second = 59
        self.BB_minute = 4
        self.BB_second = 59
        self.RB_minute = 4
        self.RB_second = 59

    def run(self):
        self._root_window.mainloop()

    def _time_counter(self, minutes, seconds):
        if seconds < 60:
            seconds -= 1
        if seconds == 0:
            seconds = 59
            minutes -= 1
        return minutes, seconds

    def _blue_buff_start(self):
        self._blue_buff_label.configure(text = "{0}:{1:02d}".format(self.BB_minute,self.BB_second))
        self._root_window.update()
        self.BB_minute,self.BB_second = self._time_counter(self.BB_minute,self.BB_second)
        self._root_window.after(1000, func = self._blue_buff_start)

    def _dragon_start(self):
        self._dragon_label.configure(text = "{0}:{1:02d}".format(self.drag_minute,self.drag_second))
        self._root_window.update()
        self.drag_minute,self.drag_second = self._time_counter(self.drag_minute,self.drag_second)
        self._root_window.after(1000, func = self._dragon_start)

    def _red_buff_start(self):
        self._red_buff_label.configure(text = "{0}:{1:02d}".format(self.RB_minute,self.RB_second))
        self._root_window.update()
        self.RB_minute,self.RB_second = self._time_counter(self.RB_minute,self.RB_second)
        self._root_window.after(1000, func = self._red_buff_start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoL_JungleTimer().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the help, hahah if you want to add me my SN is BabyÄres. thanks again.

Comment: Ps. if you could give me any more hints i would appreciate there doesnt seem to be much info on the invoke method and labels do not the command method available to them so im stuck again.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a small demo that I created for my Jungle timer. It is not completed; however, it solved your problem about the button. Feel free to ask me if you don't understand my demo!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still looking over what you have here to try and fully understand whats going on. I'm gonna comment back tomorrow with any questions i might have if that's okay , thanks again!

Comment: So i did some re-arranging to my program and its much neater now but i still cant get all the times to work together. I did however get them to show up in labels and to activate it you click a button. I notice in your program you did the same thing? So, if every button click stops the previous button even how can it ever work with buttons at all? Thanks again for the continued help.

Comment: So I have been working on this all day and still haven't figured out a solution although i did try the label method, doing this is causing the same prob. I click a label to start an event and then when i go to click a second label the first stops! LOL ughh.

Comment: use the `.after()` method since it will call the function after a certain amount of time!